# How to design a command in a plugin that can be called from vimrc?

Tags: vimscript, command-line, plugin-system

I'm working on a plugin that allows users to create custom operators. The operators would apply a VimL expression to the motion or text object that the operator moves over.

### Keeping a clean user interface

I think the cleanest interface for defining the custom operators would be to use a command. I've defined a command `:MapExpress` that would be invoked something like this:

```
:MapExpress cd '/* ' . v:val . ' */'
```

This would create a Normal mode operator and a Visual mode mapping for `cd` that would surround the motion or selection in C-style comment delimiters.

Of course, here lies a problem. You can't call a command that's defined in a plugin from your `.vimrc` file.

### Less-than-satisfying workarounds

I've come up with a few workarounds that I'm not entirely happy with.

#### User uses `autocmd VimEnter *` to call the command

While this would work, it adds a lot of "mental overhead". I would guess that a lot of Vim users don't have a solid grasp on how `autocmd` works.

#### User creates a file in `~/.vim/after/plugin/` which calls the command

Again, this would work, but it has the drawback that this piece of configuration is off in its own file, easily lost and forgotten.

#### I move the command definitions into my plugin's `autoload/` directory, and the user calls some method that triggers the file to be loaded, and thus the commands to be defined

This would look like this:

```
call express#init()
MapExpress cd '/* ' . v:val . ' */'
```

Slightly better, but this would cause confusion about whether the `express#init()` method is necessary for the plugin to work at all.

### Alternatives to using a command

I also considered some alternatives to using a command to define the operator, but each has its caveats.

#### User calls a function to define the operators

This would look something like this:

```
call express#operator('cd', '"/* ".v:val." */"')
```

This is not terrible, but it has the disadvantage of requiring a quoted expression. That can be annoying when you want to use quotes in your expression.

#### User uses an `<expr>` mapping

Like this:

```
nmap <expr> cd express#nmap('"/* ".v:val." */"')
xmap <expr> cd express#xmap('"/* ".v:val." */"')
```

This has the same tedious quoted expression requirement, and also violates [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) unless you introduce a variable (not ideal).

## Okay, so what?

Here are all of my ideas and why I don't like any of them. Am I being too fussy? Is there some better solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: The autoload solution doesn't sound too bad to me, especially if you use a function name that's slightly more specific to what it's doing. It's hard to come up with a good example without knowing what other functionality your plugin had that the autoload init is *not* required for, but maybe something like `call express#initMapCommands()`? Anything that requires extra quoting, though, is a super bad idea.

Comment: This is what I'm leaning towards, I think.

Comment: @tommcdo and today I learned how `<q-args>` really works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me you are looking for `:runtime`. You can perfectly run commands defined in plugins from your .vimrc, but you have to know the plugin name (that defines it) before that.

```
" 1- Prepare the plugin-suite if it's managed through VAM/Vundle/NeoBundle/...
ActivateAddons FooBar

" 2- Be sure the plugin is loaded
runtime plugin/foobar.vim

" 3- And finally run (defensively) the command
if !exists(':FooBar')
   echo "Sorry some initializations will be ignored as foobar is nowhere to be found"
else
   FooBar abc
   FooBar 135468
endif
```

Note: unlike the autoload solution, this approach won't crash .vimrc sourcing. If an autoload plugin cannot be found (through the execution of a function), vim throws an error. `:runtime` stays silent if no plugin can be loaded.

Comment: This is a lot of work for the end user. As a plugin developer, I'm trying to minimize the effort required to use my plugin.

Comment: This solution is for a .vimrc that you may deploy where your plugin isn't installed. For a simplified installation guide, it's just `:runtime`.
Otherwise use an option as romainl suggested.

Comment: Even still, that requires the user to know where the file is. If they use a plugin manager, it could be somewhere less obvious than `plugin/`.

Comment: If they use a plugin manager, it will always be in `plugin/` -- if you organize your "project"/repository this way. Plugin managers update automatically the `'runtimepath'` option.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Answer (score 2):

A list would IMO be the easiest solution:

```
let g:pluginname_my_operators = [
    ['cd', '/* ' . v:val . ' */'],
    ['cm', '<em>' . v:val . '</em>']
]
```

Check for `g:pluginname_my_operators` when you initialize your plugin and run `:MapExpress` on each item if applicable while still allowing your users to use the command for on-the-fly definition.

Comment: This would actually need more quoting... `v:val` must be part of the string, because it is evaluated when the map internals are invoked. I think any solution involving quoting is less than ideal.